# Ubuntu 20.04.02 won't power off or restart

Tags: drivers, shutdown, radeon, reboot, restart

I reinstalled Ubuntu a couple of days ago.
Since then I've been having this problem where I can't shut down or reboot my system completely,
it goes into a black screen and stays like that, after a couple mins the fans go insane.

I tried reinstalling the grub and doing some changes, but the error didn't get fixed.

I got tired of it and reinstalled Ubuntu again, at the first shutdown it worked, second one, same thing happened, can't power off or restart again.

I don't know why but I feel it may be a problem with my gpu drivers which I think
I installed after the first reboot (https://www.amd.com/en/support/previous-drivers/graphics/radeon-rx-vega-series/radeon-rx-vega-series/radeon-rx-vega-56)

Uninstalled the amd-gpu drivers and the problem is still happening, it just stays like this

[Edit]
Uninstalled Amd drivers properly and it started working correctly.

[image]
[image]

Comment: After a new/clean installation, can you give us a list of what changes you make to the installed system to set it up? Tell us any software you install as well as any commands or changes to configs. If there are no changes to the clean installation, you've either encountered a bug (for which you should file a bug report) or there is a hardware problem that cannot be corrected with software

Comment: @Nmath Nothing system breaking, just some gnome extensions to tweak the ui, which I always use, vscode, steam, and the only thing I think could have broken it is that driver I'm taking about

Comment: Are you sure those AMD drivers are essential?  Try to use the clean installation for a while with essential applications only. Steam and vscode should be fine.   Gnome tweaks are definitely not essential & if so, you might consider using a different DE - gnome is not designed with user customization as a priority

Comment: I will try later tonight and I'll let you know what happens, thanks!

Comment: I tried rebooting and powering off and it just worked, I'm guessing it's because I uninstalled correctly those amd drivers, thanks.